# Storing stock prices in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am creating a website that does computations based on historical daily stock quotes. Right now I have 5 tables corresponding to different letters in the alphabet (organized by symbol).

This is an example of the create statements I am using to build the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `EOD_QRSTU` (
  `symbol` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `open` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `close` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `high` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `low` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`,`symbol`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The most common query is selecting the rows for a particular symbol between two dates. This table for example has about 500,000 rows right now and takes up to 8 seconds to return about 400 rows for a particular symbol within a two-year range. Why does it take so long? How do sites like Yahoo Finance load their charts so fast?
I have been thinking about storing each stock's data in its own file in the file system instead, can anyone offer some insight into this approach? If it is fast enough this way I don't even need to limit the number of rows returned, I could simply return every line in the file. Would CSV be a suitable file format?

If it matters I am using PythonAnywhere to host the site, for now, and am using Python with Flask-SQLalchemy for the backend. I also plan on migrating to AWS soon, will that solve part of the issue?

Comment: Databases are normally much faster than file systems

Comment: @RiggsFolly I already have it as a Primary Key index?

Comment: Use `explain` to understand what the query is doing.  If it's using indexes well, you are at the limit of what you can fit in memory.  Relational databases are fundamentally limited in scalability, but 500k rows like you describe should be well within the limits of a modest system.  Are your mysql server's memory settings adequate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reorder your primary key and put `symbol` before `date`.

Indexes work best when the fixed part of the index, the `symbol` is before the range searched part, `date`.

Examine this by looking at `explain {query}` and seeing how many bytes of the index is used and the query plan.

Also don't make `symbol` UTF8 if you only are using an `ascii` character set.

Comment: Thank you so much! Reordering the primary keys dropped the response time from about 8 seconds to .05 seconds for selecting all rows for a symbol.

Comment: You're welcome. Take a more detailed look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html and http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots#indexing when you start to get more complicated queries.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with danblack's Answer (PK column order, charset)

`DECIMAL(10,5)` is not big enough for BRK.A, currently at $412,802.  `INT` is not big enough for the `volume` of several indexes.

You probably want `NOT NULL` on all columns.

A different filesystem probably won't help enough to matter.

Use InnoDB.  Period.  Full stop.

How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Do you have HDD or ssd?  It sounds like your table is much less than 1GB, so I expect things to be fully cached in RAM most of the time.